# Error installing spida and p3d: type == "both" can not be used with 'repos = NULL'

Tags: install.packages

I am trying to install the `spida` and `p3d` packages, zipped on my computer, but this error message always appears:

```
Error in install.packages: type == "both" can not be used with 'repos = NULL'
```

I have already added `type = "binary"` and `type = "source"` in the code, and it still gives the error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which operating system you are using?

Comment: Windows10, 64 bits